# ng-repeat error in loading list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm fetching data from firebase db and using the array of objects for ng-repeat. But though the console shows correct data, ng-repeat is not working as expected. Once in ten times, when i fire the server, ng-repeat works somehow.

I'm not able to figure out the error in loading.

controller -

```
   .controller('dashboardHomeController',['$scope','$firebaseObject',
        function($scope,$firebaseObject){

            console.log($scope.prgList);
            var programsRef = firebase.database().ref('/programs');

            //fetching 50 latest programs added in db chronologically sorted
            programsRef.limitToLast(50).on("value",function(snapshot){

                var programsObj = snapshot.val();//setting variable to hold object of objects snapshot
                var programsKeyArray = Object.keys(programsObj);//returns only keys
                var programsArray = Object.values(programsObj);//returns array of values
                var programsObjlength = programsKeyArray.length;

                console.log(programsKeyArray,programsObjlength,programsArray);
                //setting ng-repeat list prgList
                $scope.prgList = programsArray;

                console.log($scope.prgList);
            });
        }])
```

html -

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="prog in prgList">
            <div class="row" style="border-bottom:1px solid #d7d7d7;padding-top:20px">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <img src="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <h4>{{prog.prgHeading}}</h4>
                    <p>{{prog.prgSubHeading}}</p>
                    <p>{{prog.prgLikes}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align:center">
                    <p>{{prog.prgStatus}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>                            
</div>
```

console -

```
Array [ "-KolrsdHOBNavsAJZzZC", "-KolsZZeoP2hEsnG_iTd", "-Kolt9ds9SnzSmS71t88", "-KoltuJvBLSZyqsBRYnl", "-KoluUt6Vr5YlMOG4SHG" ] 5 Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ]  app.js:247:17

Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ]
```

Comment: try to show <p>{{prgList}}</p> in your view

Answer (score 0):

it seems angular digest cycle not triggered, you should try $scope.$apply()